# How to assert something using response assertion that has different text in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to make  SOAP call in Jmeter and using Response assertion to validate the No Error in the response. It is failing all the time because each xml has different text b/w the tags.
I see my response is in different string like this No Error & No error.

Basically I want to assert that there are no errors by extracting No Error. Is there a way that I use some regular expression here regardless of what text is present in the response assertion?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `case insensitive` response assertion?

`(?i)`  ignore case

Check this:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion

Comment: One more thing I missed to ask if when the soap request failed, it will show something like this

<RecNbr>1</RecNbr> 
  <MessageID>17</MessageID> 
  <Severity>2</Severity> 
  <Text>parameter is missing.</Text> 
  
  but if it passed it will show nothing in the response.
  
  How to assert something and force my test to fail if I see anything in  RecNbr or MessageID or Severity or Text? please and thanks

Comment: @user3381098, you need to select the 'Not' option if you want something not to appear. if it appears, it is considered to be failed.